# c# WebBrowser GetElementById don't work

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control

I have this html code:

```
    <div style="font-size: 0.8em; font-weight: bold">
    <label
    for="formFile" style="margin-right: 10px">Select a file:
    </label> 
    <input
    class="text" type="file" tabindex="1" value="" id="formFile"
    name="formFile" 
    />
</div>
```

This is my code for find HtmlElement **formFile**:

```
HtmlElement oElement = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("formFile");
```

But oElement is Always null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where (when) is `HtmlElement oElement = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("formFile");` being called?

Comment: Called from a Button.

Comment: But is it after the page is completely rendered?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure, the page is complete.

Comment: Have you double checked using devtools (F12) that the rendered element really has ID=="formFile"?

Comment: Has the DocumentCompleted Event actually fired?

Comment: What is 'webBrowser1'? You haven't declared it (or shown us...)

Comment: @JimW, No, but I got the whole html code from the Webbrowser1, is not it enough?

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett Yes, the event is fired, I test it.

Comment: @ash Naturally Webbrowser1 is a Webbrowser.